# impossible to boot my laptop

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I look on internet a lot of answers but no one can fix my problem... I can't chose anyone of my OS (ubuntu, w7 & w8) because by mistake I chose the recovery system of my acer S3 without cd drive. when this program start I chose the Exit option in the first screen. the laptop restart and the screen shows the next error.

Error: unknown filesystem
grub rescue

I use the "universal usb installer" with diferent versions of ubuntu *.iso 10.10 desktop and netbook i386, also 11.04 & 12.04 desk i386.

The screen shows.

SYSLINUX 4.06 EDD... ...Peter Anvin et al
_

I change the program and I try with "UNetbooting" to create an other type of usb stick bootable.

The screen shows

SYSLINUX 4.03... ...Peter Anvin et al
_

Nothing happens.

I try with "Rescatux.iso" but is the same screen...

I modified all the different options on the BIOS but nothing change.

Somebody have an idea about how to fix it?

tx 4 your time. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not booting from USB or CD (SYSLINUX Message)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/196180/not-booting-from-usb-or-cd-syslinux-message)

Answer (score 0):

Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), update it, and click `Recommended Repair`.
Note the URL that will appear. Reboot and check if your problem is solved. Indicate the URL if any problem.

[image]